# Distribution of a centered standardized sample

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, proof

Foreword : this is **not** homework, but a real problem : in a Bayesian model comparison context, I am trying to work out the correct prior density of mixed-model parameters which are, for computational reasons, computed as the centered and standardized means of other "raw" parameters, which are themselves given prior distributions. See Gelman A, Hill J. *Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models*. 1st ed. Cambridge University Press; 2006. This textbook uses this trick (or variants thereof) quite often, and various simulations have convinced me of its efficacy, at least in selected cases.

I currently do not have on hand any reference material (textbook, etc...) for this question, whose answer is quite probably a standard result. Could someone lend me a hand (if only by pointing me to a Web-accessible reference, which my Google attempts have been unsuccessful at referring me to) ?

Let $X=X_1,\ldots X_N$ be a sample (i. e.  vector of $N$ *independent* random variables sampled from the same) **normal** distribution ${\textrm N}(\mu_x, \sigma^2_x)$. Let $m={{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i} \over N}$ and $s^2={{\sum (X_i)^2} \over {N-1}}$  the unbiased estimators of the mean and variance of this distribution. What is the (joint) distribution of the *components* $Y_i$ of $Y={{X-m} \over s}$ ?

I am sorely tempted to answer that they are $N$ independent normal standard random variables (i. e. distributed as ${\textrm N}(0, 1)$), and my intuition is seconded by various simulation results, but I have trouble ***proving*** it.

What I know (or prove to my satisfaction) can be summarized as follows :

- $m$ has a ${\textrm N}(\mu_x, {{\sigma^2_x} \over N})$ distribution ; therefore, the common mean of the $Y_i$ is 0 (trivial from the definition of the mean).
- The common variance of the $Y_i$ is 1 (a trifle less trivial but can be worked out from the definition).
- ${s^2} \over {\sigma^2_x}$ has a $\chi^2_{N-1}$ distribution  (classical  result that I remember having worked out).
- Any textbook will state that $m \over s$ has a $t_{N-1}(0, 1)$
  distribution (*Not* trivial, but I remember having worked it out, the crucial point being the independence of $m$ and $s$. I think that this historically is the origin of the distinction of the $t$ distribution, BTW...).
- Obviously, $Y_i={{X_i} \over s}-{m \over s}$.

However, neither $m$ nor $s$ are independent of the $X_i$. Therefore

- the distribution of ${X_i} \over s$ is unknown (to me), and
- the distribution of the sum is *not* the convolution of the distribution of its terms.

Where am I goofing ?

Comment: It is not m/s that has the student t distribution it is (m-μ$_x$)/s. Why are you interested in the joint distribution of the components of the Y vector?

Comment: Because if I know the distribution of ${(X-\mu_X)} \over \sigma$, (normal(0, 1), of course), I want to be able to use the distribution of ${(X-m)} \over s$, which is the propre prior distribution to use when these $X$ are themselves parameters in a Bayesian model. See an example of this use in Gelman's regression textbook (2007) about IRT models, when he uses this trick to get a better convergence of the IRT coefficients ; I'd like to have an explicit derivation instead of blind faith in BUGS sampling. PS : you're right $m \over s$ has a $t(\mu_x, 1, N-1)$ distribution.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I guess you wanted a finite-sample result, not an asymptotic one. But if $n$ is large, the argument below shows why you'll be close to independent Normals.

Isn't this just an application of Slutsky's Theorem? Write:

$$\frac{X - m}{s} = \frac{\sigma}{s}\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} + \frac{\sigma}{s}\frac{\mu - m}{\sigma}$$

Then note that $\frac{\sigma}{s} \rightarrow 1$, $\mu - m \rightarrow 0$, and $\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \sim N(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to myself : I no longer think that this problem is (directly) solvable, because the transformation I study (i. e. centering and standardizing) is not a bijection : $Z=\alpha{}X$ will have the same image as $X$ (whenever $\alpha\neq{}0$, of course), as well as $T=X+\gamma$. Therefore, the classic "Jacobian" results do not (can not !) apply : the reverse transformation is not defined...

More sophisticated methods (e. g. moment-generating functions) hint (strongly) in the direction of a normal(0, 1) as a limit for a sample size going to infinity. I am not sophisticated enough (good enough) to push in this direction in the finite case.

Sorry for a question that should have appear either stupid or non-solvable at first glance...

Comment: Of *course* the transformation is not a bijection, because the components of $Y$ are not dependent: they must sum to zero and their squares must sum to $N-1$. But that does not imply the problem has no solution! Indeed, once you observe the $Y_i$ are identically distributed, you ought to be able to deduce a tremendous amount about them (because you can easily compute their first few moments).